# JVM Search fallback for install4j Application

Tags: java, install4j, exe4j

Our Application installed with install4j searches for JavaVM in the Path of EXE4J_JAVA_HOME Environment if our configured JRE isn't available?
Is there a way to disable this fallback feature?

Comment: There is currently no way to disable this fallback. What is your use case?

Comment: Our Application is used in regulated environments and we have to make sure our application doesn't behave in another way then intended by starting with an other JRE but we have a feature that checks if the installation has been manipulated which needs to be done to start it with another JRE so its no real problem just would have been nice to prevent it from using the Environment variable

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I've added this to our issue tracker.